# Review audits in close votes

Tags: discussion, review-audit

Just a few minutes ago, I was reviewing close votes. No problem, I thought. I usually pass these. So, I got [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/207453), and voted to close. I failed somehow, but, as you can see from the link, the question deserves to be closed. What is going on here?

Comment: This was probably introduced into the set of audits because it was an upvoted and answered question before it was vandalized by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the edit history, it seems evident that the OP was defacing a question with good answers.